# iOS: Using base storyboard to internationalize app, how to set the object name in string file?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, interface-builder, uistoryboard

On iOS6 and later, developer can use base storyboard + string file to internationalize storyboard. But the string file is quite strange:

```
/* Class = "IBUILabel"; text = "Content"; ObjectID = "NCi-dy-oDo"; */
"NCi-dy-oDo.text" = "Content";
```

The name of widgets in it is quite strange, how can I set this name?